# Is this an equivalent "while" replacement for the "for"?

Tags: c++

Supposing we have defined a class `T` with no restrictions and three functions `cond`, `next` and `f` returning `bool`, `void` and anything respectively, are

```
for(T k = T(); cond(); next())
    f();
```

and

```
{
T k = T();

while(cond()) {
    f();
    next();
}
}
```

the same algorithmically speaking?

Comment: Is there anything specific in your C++ book's explanation of how the `for` statement works that you don't quite understand?

Comment: I'd post an answer, but "Yes." is too short.

Comment: @melpomene The remainder of a "short answer" can be easily filled up with a link to documentation and an excerpt..

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for#Explanation

Comment: If you are going to vote-to-close, please pick an *appropriate* reason. Or is the question *really* "unclear"? I don't find it so. Too many high-horses stampeding about.

Comment: Isn’t it your homework to find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. A `for (init; cond; step) {statements}` syntax is equivalent to

```
{
    init;
    while (cond) {
        statements;
        step;
    }
}
```

So they are totally interchangeable (except for readability in certain cases).

The purpose of the standalone braces in the first and the last line is to restrict the scope of the initialized variables to the loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since in both the cases you have initialized the class object and then the check condition and then the next step to be followed are identically placed both will work similarly algorithmically as well as in execution owing to the fact that both FOR and WHILE are interconvertible .